# Streaming S3 object to VertX Http Server Response

Tags: amazon-s3, stream, vert.x

The title basically explains itself.

I have a REST endpoint with `VertX`. Upon hitting it, I have some logic which results in an `AWS-S3` object.

My previous logic was not to upload to `S3`, but to save it locally. So, I can do this at the response `routerCxt.response().sendFile(file_path...)`.

Now that the file is in S3, I have to download it locally before I could call the above code.

That is slow and inefficient. I would like to stream S3 object directly to the `response` object.

In `Express`, it's something like this. `s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res);`.

I read a little bit, and saw that `VertX` has a class called `Pump`. But it is used by `vertx.fileSystem()` in the examples.

I am not sure how to plug the `InputStream` from `S3`'s`getObjectContent()` to the `vertx.fileSystem()` to use `Pump`.

I am not even sure `Pump` is the correct way because I tried to use `Pump` to return a local file, and it didn't work.

```
    router.get("/api/test_download").handler(rc -> {
        rc.response().setChunked(true).endHandler(endHandlr -> rc.response().end());
        vertx.fileSystem().open("/Users/EmptyFiles/empty.json", new OpenOptions(), ares -> {
            AsyncFile file = ares.result();
            Pump pump = Pump.pump(file, rc.response());
            pump.start();
        });
    });
```

Is there any example for me to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done if you use the Vert.x `WebClient` to communicate with S3 instead of the Amazon Java Client.

The `WebClient` can pipe the content to the HTTP server response:

```
webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setDefaultHost("s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com"));

router.get("/api/test_download").handler(rc -> {
HttpServerResponse response = rc.response();
response.setChunked(true);
webClient.get("/my_bucket/test_download")
 .as(BodyCodec.pipe(response))
  .send(ar -> {
    if (ar.failed()) {
      rc.fail(ar.cause());
    } else {
      // Nothing to do the content has been sent to the client and response.end() called
    }
  });
});
```

The trick is to use the `pipe` [body codec](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_decoding_responses).

Comment: Thanks. That took me a step in the right direction. Is there any header that I should add to the `response`'s `headers`? When I didn't add any extra `header`, it doesn't download it, when I added `Content-Type: binary/octet-stream`, it is downloading a blank file. I tested the temp url beforehand, and it does download it. So, that's probably not a cause.

Comment: Seems like a separate problem. It would be better to post a complete reproducer on the Vert.x forum.

Comment: hey.. I figured it out.. it was a novice mistake, nth important. thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up!